# How do I keep a local version of a conclicted file in TFS?

Tags: tfs, conflict

I did a Get All from my TFS server, and there are a few dozen conflicts. I'd like to keep the local versions of these files, but the only option I'm given is "Overwrite Local Version". How do I tell it to keep my local copy?

Answer (score 1):

TFS will try to merge the changes automatically. If it is unable to do so, then it will have show there is a conflict. Typically you'll see an option for the overwrite with server version, keep local version, or do a manual merge of the changes.

Comment: But I don't. I only see the option to overwrite using the server version.